# Detect device types from user agent strings

Tags: java, browser, user-agent

I am trying to detect "desktop", "mobile", and "tablet" from user agent strings. What I need is just these three rough categories. Brand and device names are not needed. Some examples of user agent I have are:

"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36"

Is there any existing API can do this?

According to the very last sentence of [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), it seems that looking for keyword "mobi" in a user agent string can handle most cases. But it seems too easy to be true......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [UADetector library](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/) that does just that. It has device categorization feature added since 0.9.10 version.

> UADetector is a library to identify over 190 different desktop and mobile browsers and 130 other User-Agents like feed readers, email clients and multimedia players. In addition, even more than 400 robots like BingBot, Googlebot or Yahoo Bot can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious: Why does the device type matter?

Not trying to be snarky, but trying to understand a use case.

[In Cordova you can check for this,](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html) but now sure about straight HTML. I which I have done for iOS before. I needed to do this to detect when I needed to add a 20px margin to the header of a page on a Cordova app, as iOS made this change several versions ago.

Here is how I did it:

```
    if (parseFloat(window.device.version) >= 7.0 ) {
        $allHeaders.css( "margin-top", "20px" );       
    }
```

Comment: One use case is in online advertising. Some ads are only successful on certain device types. An ad for pizza delivery would probably be most interesting to users who are at home ... so you might decide to display it only on desktop devices.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DeviceTypeDetector {
    public static String getDeviceType(String userAgent) {
        String deviceType;
        Pattern tabletPattern = Pattern.compile("(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobi))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher tabletMatcher = tabletPattern.matcher(userAgent);
        Pattern mobilePattern = Pattern.compile("(mobi|phone|blackberry|opera mini|fennec|minimo|symbian|psp|nintendo ds)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mobileMatcher = mobilePattern.matcher(userAgent);
        if (tabletMatcher.find()) {
            deviceType = "tablet";
        } else if (mobileMatcher.find()) {
            deviceType = "mobile";
        } else {
            deviceType = "desktop";
        }
        return deviceType;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4537.110 Safari/537.36";
        System.out.println(getDeviceType(userAgent));
    }
}
```